# How to support landscape mode on iOS? shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation gets called only once

Tags: ios

I'm trying to support landscape mode in my gl iOS application. I have a window, a gl view, and a view controller with one method, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, which returns YES. This is how I set them up:

```
 window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

 GLView *glView = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
 glView.delegate = self;

 view_controller = [ViewController alloc];
 view_controller.view = glView;
 window.rootViewController = view_controller;
```

This happens on the method applicationDidFinishLaunching. The problem is that the method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation gets called only once, for the portrait mode. I still get events on my view, but the method for auto rotate never gets called again.

Am I setting this up right? There are no nib files, just code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling init on your ViewController instance (is it a UIViewController subclass?)

You should be overriding the following UIViewController methods

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

The call to should autorotate does not mean that the rotation will take place, this is explained in the UIViewController class reference

> By default, the UIViewController class displays views in portrait mode
>   only. To support additional orientations, you must override the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return YES for any
>   orientations your subclass supports. If the autoresizing properties of
>   your views are configured correctly, that may be all you have to do.
>   However, the UIViewController class provides additional hooks for you
>   to implement additional behaviors as needed.
>
> To temporarily turn off features that are not needed or might
>   otherwise cause problems during the orientation change, you can
>   override the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method and
>   perform the needed actions there. You can then override the
>   didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method and use it to reenable those
>   features once the orientation change is complete.
>
> To add animations for an orientation change, override the
>   willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method and perform
>   your animations there.

Comment: Yeah the problem was I wasn't calling init. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation should be enough, the others are if you want to be notified during the rotation animation